# How can i update progress bar from 0.0 to 1.0 values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, algorithm, math, progress-bar

how can i update progress bar correctly?

I have a loop in seconds... from 60 to 0 (x--) and I need to update correctly progress bar.
What matematically method i need use to update bar?, considering that bar values are from 0.0 to 1.0 ???

```
NSLog(@"PROGRESS: %2.2f", ABS(log(100/x)) );
[countDownBar setProgress:ABS(log(100/x)) ];
```

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Progress bar counting up:

```
(60.0 - x) / 60.0
```

Progress bar counting down:

```
x / 60.0
```

Comment: perfect... as you can see I'm not a master of mathematics!